# Access to MySQL Migration / Hebrew values turn into question marks (??????)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, collation

Ho, i have an access database which i need to export to mysql, i have the MySQL Migration Tools installed and i can actually copy the data the problem is that hebrew entries in the table are converted to question marks (????????).
I've tried playing around in PHPMyAdmin server database and table collation/character sets, even in the mySQL Migration Tools you can set the source and target collation but every time the result is: ???????.
originally i tried mySQL Workbench to migrate from SQL Server to MySQL where i have a replica of the same Access database but i only get Question Marks.
I'm not an expert in Collations and Character Sets, I would really appreciate if someone can help me out with the right collations and character set to set MySQL, I've been struggling with this for quite a while and can not find a solution online.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a program that did the migrating without any problems SQLyog Ultimate 
Thanks